# Returning a Promise in Node.js

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I can't wrap my head around this.

Take the following three functions where `a` calls `b`, and `b` calls `c`:

```
const c = () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(new Date());
        }, "1750");
    });
};

const b = async () => {
    const result = await c();
    console.log("b(): %s", result);
    return result;
};

const a = async () => {
    const result = await b();
    console.log("a(): %s",result);
    return result;
};

console.log("Starting...");
const final_result = a();
console.log("Final Result: %s", final_result);
console.log("Ending...");
```

I expected `b()` to wait-for/get the result of the promise returned by `c()`, and pass the value to `a()`. However, it looks like the promise gets passed all the way up the call stack.

[image]

To get the behavior I want, I have to handle the promise in each function:

```
const c = () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(new Date());
        }, "1750");
    });
};

const b = async () => {
    const result = await c();
    console.log("b(): %s", result);
    return result;
};

const a = async () => {
    const result = await b();
    console.log("a(): %s",result);
    return result;
};
(async () => {
    console.log("Starting...");
    const final_result = await a();
    console.log("Final Result: %s", final_result);
    console.log("Ending...");
})()
```

[image]

Why can't I just get the result of the promise in one function and return that? And, if I can do it, how?

Comment: So basically you want to return a value from an async function? You want the value and not a promise

Comment: Yes!! @PatrickHollweck you understand me!!

Comment: You can not do that, That is not possible. Once you make something async there is no way to make it sync again.[Read this relevant existing question :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) Is there a reason for why you cant handle/await the promise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)